# Regex to verify filename and relative path with no upward navigation (..\) in Windows

Tags: c#, windows, regex, naming-conventions, user-input

I'm trying to verify that a filename and path input by the user is structurally correct in a C# GUI.  I do not need to make sure the file exists, just that the name is a valid windows file name and the path is a valid relative path from the present working directory.  Absolute paths must be explicitly denied. Regex was never my thing.

Accepted inputs would be:
"myfiles\mydocument.pdf"
"Another_folder\an0th3r_fi1e.fake"
".\folder\file.docx" (current directory designation)

Rejected inputs would be:
"C:\anything"
"internal folder\files??*>\myfile.pdf"
"folder\file " (whitespace at beginning or end)
"....\folder located elsewhere\file.txt" (upward navigation)

Thanks for any help!

As a loose guide: [MSDN 'Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces'](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: you'll need lots of unit-tests for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
@"(\.\\)?([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+[.a-zA-Z0-9_-]*\\)*[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+[.a-zA-Z0-9_-]*"
```

*Note that this is [vulnerable to a DDOS attack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff646973.aspx)*.

Comment: Thanks for that!  I'm giving it a look over now; it seems to work for what I need.  I appreciate the article.  It was an interesting read.